# Creating href link to a local removable storage device on Linux

Tags: html, linux, hyperlink, download, href

So the problem is this, I have a Raspberry Pi running some Linux OS, not 100% which one (kind of new to Linux /: ), with Apache installed. I have an **index.html** file setup under **/var/www/** which I want to have an href link to download a file. The problem is that I want the file to be on a flashdrive connected to the Pi.

Is there a way to navigate back to the **/media/** file from the Apache location within **/var/www/**?

I know that one can use **"file:///DIRECTORY_GOES_HERE/** but that doesn't work. I am connecting to the Pi, which is connected to my network, via my PC using Firefox. I simply type in the local IP address and I get the index page. This looks like this, **"10.0.0.14/DIRECTORY**.

As one might imagine, the href doesn't work because the result of the aforementioned code would be, **10.0.0.14/file:///DIRECTORY_GOES_HERE/**

This doesn't work.

The desired result is for an HTML href link to somehow navigate back to the media file to download whatever the link is linked to.

This is an example of how I am attempting to change the directory of the file being downloaded

`<a href="/media/">Something cool</a>`

If anyone can provide any help at all, it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

No. By design. If that was possible you would be able to download any file from any server running apache. You have to connect to Pi in a different way, i.e. via [ssh](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh/).